# Submitting Javascript form values

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I have a mobile quiz, that I load 10 form questions into hidden divs, and after each question is answered, I fade and hide the question and unhide the next question, after they go through the 10 questions, how do I get it to post the actual data to the script waiting on the server  ...form method=post action=process_quiz.php..   I am not really sure where/how to add that final submit button (obviously in the last div) but to work with the Javascript code to post the form data.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 


        $('.btnNext').click(function()
        {

                $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function()
                {
                    $(this).next().fadeIn(500);
                });

        }); 

            $('.btnPrev').click(function()
            {
                $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function()
                {
                    $(this).prev().fadeIn(500);
                });


            });     
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#mySubmit").click(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

As long as the form has the following attributes defined:

```
<form action="process_quiz.php" method="post">
```

The documentation for jQuery form .submit() function is located here:
http://api.jquery.com/submit/

It doesn't really matter where the button is located, or if it is even a submit button with the code above. If it is an actual submit button located within the form DOM element then it will automatically submit the form on click without you needing to specify it.

Comment: P.s. top comment for the jQuery documentation for .submit() was 'If you're tearing your hair over why submit() just isn't submitting a form, make sure that the submit input tag does not have name="submit" as an attribute, or jQuery won't submit the form.'

Comment: F*(&, i always write too much in my answers lol - tooooo slow

Comment: According to the docs: `Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method`

Comment: The docs also link to [**DOMLint**](http://kangax.github.com/domlint/) - which states: `Names of form controls are populated as properties of "parent" form element and might conflict with "actual" properties of a form element (either own or inherited via "interface chain")`